# I am looking for a youtube video or short film about humans and immortality

Tags: story-identification, short-film

The film starts off when a human found a way to escape death by using nano machines. A lot of humans were overjoyed by this and after about 100,000 years most humans look like cyborgs and were living in space.  The person who found a way to escape death had a son.  His son said he was tired of living and wanted to return to the cycle of death and most other humans wanted the same thing leaving him alone.

Comment: Sounds like a Dust film

Comment: Yeah, check the Dust channel especially if the production was well polished.

Comment: Okay I will see if I can find the video ty